# How to Change Precision of Export / Add Geometry Columns field

Tags: qgis, precision

I would like to display the coordinates of a number of points on a map.  I can use Vector > Export / Add Geometry Columns which adds coordinates to 6 dp.  However as I am using a UTM-type projection this level of (false) precision is not necessary.

I can copy the values to another predefined column in Field Calc, but would need to do this every time I updated or added a point.  Is there a way of changing the default precision value for Export / Add...  ?

Edit - I am using QGIS 2.0.1 Dufour

Comment: You mentioned using QGIS 2.0.1. Would you consider using QGIS >=2.6? You could then create **Virtual** fields which when you add an expression, it would automatically update each feature with this expression. So in your case, the coordinates would be updated each time you add/modify points.